# How to deploy .net Blazor Web Assembly Project in iis

Tags: iis, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to deploy .Net 6.0 Blazor Web Assembly project in iis.I have installed below dependency in iis server.But its not working.Please check below screenshot and advise how to do this.

dependency software installed in iis server :-

1.Microsoft .Net 6.0.6 Windows Server Hosting
2.Microsoft .Net SDK 6.0.301 (X86)

Screenshot :-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, after the program is deployed, are you having problems accessing it in IIS?

From the screenshot you provided, all we can see is that there is something wrong with your domain configuration. You can check the IP settings in DNS. In addition, you also need to bind the domain name in IIS.

Related Doc:

[Up and running with Azure VM and GoDaddy domain](http://www.jamespgilbert.com/2021/02/up-and-running-with-azure-vm-and-godaddy-domain/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you purchase their VPS or shared hosting? From above error message, it is DNS issue, have you contacted their support team? Godaddy is using Plesk as control panel, you might try to read this tutorial about deploying your .net core files, https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-5-on-asphostportal-hosting/.